# Стандарт ARIA

Tags: html5

Всем привет я тут узнал про стандарт ARIA для HTML5, но толкового разяснения на русском языке, не нашёл, может вы подскажете какие-нибудь сайты на эту тему?

Answer (score 1):

На русском языке:

- http://www.slideshare.net/Gleb2/w3c-standards-for-rich-internet-applications-accessibility-wai-aria
- http://webknowledge.ru/primeneniye-wai-aria-landmarks-2013/
- http://html5ru.com/sostoyaniya-i-svojstva-obektov-aria-atributy.html

Answer (score 0):

Некие семантические фичи для людей с затруднениями. [Полная информация от W3C](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/).

Comment: "Некие семантические фичи для людей с затруднениями". Имхо, очень неудачная формулировка. Лучше сказать: атрибуты для повышения доступности сайта.